# does flash 8 and AS2 have webcam controls?

Tags: actionscript

I've been looking at opensource tools, but turns out my roommate has an old version of flash. All the webcam tuts I've seen don't work in this, i'm wondering if webcam controls even exist in as2 and if someone could possibly provide a simple explanation on how to make them work?

I have wowza media server running on my host and I want to be able to broadcast my webcam on a website using it.

Comment: stab your roomm8 and use as3 -.^

Comment: I would also recommend AS3. Since you will be rarely be using the timeline for webcam application, I would recommend using a nice IDE like FlashDevelop ( http://www.flashdevelop.org/ ). For assets, you could compile swfs with your roommate's old version of flash and either use the assets(control skins) either by loading the SWF at runtime, either by embedding them (with the [Embed] metadata tag)

Answer (score 1):

[`Camera`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/help.html?content=00000862.html#182292)
[`NetConnection`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/00001390.html#414318)
[`NetStream`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/00001394.html#415798)
[`Video`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/00001692.html#540612)